# Word 2013 Macro Save as Text - suppress dialogs

Tags: office-2013, word-2013, save-dialog

I am batch converting many word 2013 documents to text and saving them with the ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 command. Does anyone know of a way to suppress nag dialogs such as "the document may contain text content that will be lost upon conversion..." ?

It is quite bothersome in a long run to have to occasionally hit enter so that the conversion process will continue.

Answer (score 0):

There is:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
```

More information

[Application.DisplayAlerts Property (Word)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192373.aspx)

[WdAlertLevel Enumeration (Word)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840055.aspx)